# JFreeChart: add code after Zoom() - to prevent disappearing Tick Labels

Tags: java, jfreechart

I  have created an app that used JFreeChart to make an XYLineChart (among other things) but recently encountered a bug within JFreeChart whereby if the chart's x or y-axis was set to a very small range (either low values or minimal difference between the values of the x or y-axis), the chart would be plotted as usual but all the tick labels on the said axis would disappear. This also happens if a chart is zoomed in too far by the user.

I have managed to get around this by adding a button in my app's UI that allows users to refresh the axis after the chart is made or zoomed into. The action listener of this button re-sets the tick labels and they then show up correctly on the axes.

Now, I want this to be done automatically instead of using the button I made. For this, I need to place this code somewhere in the Chart Panel creation where it is executed immediately after the ChartPanel.zoom() method finishes execution.

My question is, when a user zooms into a chart, what happens after the zoom() code finishes executing ? Where does the control go next ? Or, is there a way to add in a few lines of code to be executed every time after the zoom() method executes ?

If anyone has any suggestions, kindly let me know as soon as possible. Thanks.

Comment: any suggestions ?? I'm looking to find where to place my code so that it executes after the Chart Panel is zoomed in ? which method controls this: zoom() or zoomInBoth() ?

Answer (score 0):

I've handled zoom events by adding a `PlotChangeListener` to the `Plot` object. This will be called after a variety of events, one of which is zooming. E.g.:

```
chart.getPlot().addChangeListener(new PlotChangeListener(){
  @Override
  public void plotChanged(PlotChangeEvent event)
  {
    System.out.println("I am called after a zoom event (and some other events too).");
  }});
```